# how to write onBackPressed() in fragment kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, fragment, onbackpressed

I created 4 fragments in my dashboard activity

1, 2,3,4
And on Back Button Press I must return from 4 to 1, 3 to 1, 2 to 1

What is the best practice to do that?

My app must not return recently open fragments like 4 to 3, 3 to 4

Comment: Keep popping the fragments out of backstack when moving forward. E.g. when you go from 2 to 3, remove 2 from backstack and when going from 3 to 4, remove 3 from backstack.

Comment: Are you using NavController? This question is extremely similar to another question today from someone with a very similar user name. Is this an alternate account asking about the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

override on `onBackPressed()` method in activity and write this code snippet. I think solve your problem

```
 @Override fun onBackPressed() {
    while (supportFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                if (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container) is Fragment1) {
                    return
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()
            }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use Jetpack Navigation, it provides you with a GUI that you can see all the destination in your navigation structure.

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation?
gclid=Cj0KCQiA15yNBhDTARIsAGnwe0UOz85aXEUlPqKU7VnbeGQKAwGufnfxbxTZDNyj6670Oxu3PbkyjtoaAnk4EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds